# SnapshotCM to TFS migration

Tags: tfs, version-control, azure-devops

One of our Project requirement wants to migrate SnapshotCM to TFS. I searched in internet, but didn't find any links or document.

Is it possible to migrate snapshotCM to TFS with version control history?

If it's possible, please provide me the documentation or some links to do.

Comment: Just want tot confirm any process on this issue? Is below explaintion is help for you? Don't hesitate to leave comment if you still has puzzle. Or you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to migrate snapshotCM to TFS with version control
>   history?

As I know, there hasn't such possible can support migrate repos from `snapshotCM` to `TFS`. For **TFS**, it only support `Git` and `TFVC` version control tools. Until now, what we supported is migrate between TFVC and Git.

You can raise a feature suggestion ticket in our [official community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). Then the relevant microsoft development team would review this suggestion and consider whether it would be added into our develop roadmap.